# C# unassigned local variable when using switch statement

Tags: c#, csv, variables

I have been writing a program that takes data from a microcontroller and saves it to a csv file using c#. I have been having some issues when it comes to properly assigning variables, I have hit a point where I am quite confused as to why my code doesn't compile in C# but doing a similar process in embedded c works fine.
I declare my strings prior to a switch statement; and after the switch the variables I get an error saying "use of an unassigned variable". 
I have put some comments next to these declarations of a direct copy from one of the cases in the switch statement and when I do this the function runs; but it doubles the data in the "S1_test" csv; I assume this is due to the repetition of the file location. Even though this is the case, it saves all the data as normal and as I expect. 
A similar problem occurs with the data itself; which is saving into the "string[] values;" variable.
When I assign these variables nothing (for example: string filepath = null;) I get no error but the data does not save and function does not work correctly.
How do I correctly assign these two variables? I don't seem to be grasping C# as well as the embedded programming I wrote for the controller.
The function I am having trouble with is below:

```
    public void DatatoCSV(int sensor)
    {
        int number = sensor;
        string[] stringSeparator = new string[] { "," };

        /* this is where I am having troubles when i add the comments in the code will work but I get multiples in "S1_test.csv" file */
        string filepath; /*= @"C:\Users\GTProject\Documents\****\Temperature Characterisation\csv_test\S1_test.csv";*/
        string[] values;/*= sensor1Data.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);*/

        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        // changes the variables required depending on what sensor data is being saved
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:

                values = sensor1Data.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                filepath = @"C:\Users\GTProject\Documents\****\Temperature Characterisation\csv_test\S1_test.csv";
                break;

            case 2:
                values = sensor2Data.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                filepath = @"C:\Users\GTProject\Documents\****\Temperature Characterisation\csv_test\S2_test.csv";
                break;

            case 3:
                values = sensor3Data.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                filepath = @"C:\Users\GTProject\Documents\****\Temperature Characterisation\csv_test\S3_test.csv";
                break;

            case 4:
                values = sensor4Data.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None);
                filepath = @"C:\Users\GTProject\Documents\****\Temperature Characterisation\csv_test\S4_test.csv";
                break;

            default:
                /*run some function*/
                break;
        }

        /* values will be unassigned... BUT I GAVE IT MEANING IN THE SWITCH STATEMENT!?!?  */
        // values to be saved 
        var sensor_number   = values[0];
        var sensor_reading  = values[1];
        var sensor_status   = values[2];
        var sensor_temp     = values[3];

        // sets up the string that is going to be saved to the csv
        var newline = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", sensor_number, sensor_reading, sensor_status, sensor_temp);


        // creates an appended line format of the string created above
        csv.AppendLine(newline);

        /* here it will say that 'filepath' is unassigned -WHY!? *INTERNAL RAGE* */
        // saves the string to the csv filepath
        File.AppendAllText(path: filepath, contents: csv.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Unless you are assigning to `values` in the `default` case as well, it's possible to reach the end of the `switch` block without assigning to `values`, thus the compilation error. a variables must GUARANTEED to have a value, not assumed.

Comment: You should feel good that C# is safer and warn you of possible errors. (although GCC with `-Wall` often works well too)

Comment: Regarding `string[] values` before using it and you need to set the array size before hand ex. `string[] values= new values[10]`  Refer for more here: [link]https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-array

Comment: oh my lord how did I not see this.... I have added in a quick check using the default of the switch statement to avoid this; you a lifesaver - you deserve a cookie!

Comment: Late to the party, but if you truly only accept the numbers 1 through 4, you need to do something like throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(sensor)) in the default case. That will keep the compiler happy.

Comment: Long story short; dont leave the default case in a switch statement blank; the compiler doesn't like it

Comment: @abhijeetchimankar - I know this is a good idea; I have left it as it is for now because I still need to work on the code of the sensors too. Once I know what data I'll be sending to the PC I'll adjust the size of the array to suit

Comment: @Alex_embedded I am getting confused. 1. when you are assigning value to `values` why are you not getting error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'` 2. why is your string array is not giving error on console like this when you're not defining it `Array creation must have array size or array initializer`. 3. If you give value as `value[0]="boo"` without initalizing, you should have got compile error `Use of unassigned local variable 'values'`

Answer (score 1):

> values will be unassigned... BUT I GAVE IT MEANING IN THE SWITCH STATEMENT!?!?

No you did not. What if `number` is greater than 4? The `default` case does not seem to initialize your variables.

*All* possible ways through the `switch` statement *must* initialize the variables. As long as there is *one* way to come through without initializing them, the compiler will consider them potentially uninitialized.

Comment: This was my frustrated self getting mad at a computer for doing its job. 
The fact is that the number can't be greater than 4 but this is an assumption and the compiler doesn't take assumptions; I have added a check in the default case to make 100% certain that only 1 to 4 will do something; if these numbers don't show it will trigger an error function I am yet to create. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
        default:
            values = null;
            filepath = null;
            break;
```

What do you mean, what value would have values and filepath is number won't 1,2,3 or 4? Every one vriable must be initialised everyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

As mentioned by the brilliant @jmcilhinney my default statement was empty; although you may be certain that your switch statement holds all possible answers the compiler does not make assumptions. The default also needs to do something with the variables so the compiler is 'happy'. This is @jmcilhinney comment:

Unless you are assigning to values in the default case as well, it's possible to reach the end of the switch block without assigning to values, thus the compilation error. a variables must GUARANTEED to have a value, not assumed. – jmcilhinney